# Is it necessary to recompile a view after an index is created in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, indexing, view

I have a table suppose T1(F1,F2,F3).
Then I create a complex view using T1(F1) column and T1(F2) column.
Then after a while I create an index on F1 column of T1.

So will my new index be used by the existing view or do I need to recompile it so that its execution plan is updated?

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: Check the execution plan.

Answer (score 1):

The index is used immediately, recompile is not required. Perhaps it needs to be recompiled when you create a function-based index as this adds a (hidden) column to the table (but I never tested).

Anyway, when you select a view which is not valid then Oracle first tries to recompile it automatically, so a manual recompile is not needed in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are not talking about a materialized view, then a query using the view can use the index.